# Remove multiple rows from an array object

Tags: c#, arrays, double, row

Is there a **better** way of removing *multiple rows* from the below `double array`?

```
double[] RetDist;

HashSet<int> rowsToRemove = new HashSet<int> { 249, 250, 251,252,253,254,255,256,257,258,259,260,261,262,263,264,265,266,267,268,269};

RetDist = dataDist.Where((source, index) =>  !rowsToRemove.Contains(index)).ToArray();
```

**Main concern**: Assuming I have 1000 (*extreme case*) rows to be removed, *it could be very inefficient to specify manually:*

```
HashSet<int> rowsToRemove = new HashSet<int> { 249, 250,...};
```

**EDIT -** *Way around used so far:*

1. Convert `array[]` to `List<>`

   ```
   List<double> Lretdist = RetDist.ToList();
   ```
2. Remove series of `indexes` via `method` (*that I wanted to avoid initially*)

   ```
   List<double> test = RemoveIndexRowFromList(Lretdist, "m");

     public static List<double> RemoveIndexRowFromList(List<double> lst, string  obsfrequency)
   {
       int idx, totalrow, endindex, del;    
       totalrow = lst.Count;

       switch (obsfrequency)
       {
           case "d":

               idx = 1;
               endindex = totalrow - idx;

               while (endindex < totalrow)
               {
                   del = totalrow - 1;
                   lst.RemoveAt(del);
                   totalrow = lst.Count;
               }

               break;

           case "m":

               idx = 20;
               endindex = totalrow - idx;

               while (endindex < totalrow)
               {
                   del = totalrow - 1;
                   lst.RemoveAt(del);
                   totalrow = lst.Count ;
               }

               break;
       }

       return lst;
   }
   ```
3. Switch back to `array[]`

   ```
   double[] Re = test.ToArray(); // and keep remaining computations using arrays
   ```

**Ps**: *I concede that these 3 additional steps might be a bit `sub-optimal` but it 
I guess it's relatively better than `hard-coding` the number of rows to be removed.*

Comment: Have a look at Except in Linq: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @IanofOz: `Enumerable.Except<TSource>` would more or less require, likewise the above solution, the manual specification of a second `double[] object` containing `indexes` of the rows to be removed (see examples). My aim is to know **if**  _there are successful ways of achieving something like_ `RetDist = dataDist.Where((source, index) => index > 249).ToArray()`

Comment: a normal array is not the best choice if you need tot remove or add huge amount of data to start with. For relative fast random access a List<T> would be a better choice.

Comment: "it could be very inefficient to specify manually..." from where do you get the data that has to be removed ? Or how do you know what needs to be removed ?

Comment: Your index > 249 example looks to be a new requirement from the original question. As Jim's suggested, we need some more details about your requirements. And in practice I suspect if you're not doing this over and over again performance won't be a major concern - even if there's 1000 rows to be removed.

Comment: @Jim: i retrieve my data from `SQL` as `DataTable`, then making lots of simulation using a `double[,] object` ending up with the above `double[] object`. Given the different observation periods on which my simulations are based (i.e 1 yr, etc.) I know `ex-ante` the rows to be removed in the final `double[] object`.

Comment: @IanofOz: i guess, performance won't be at stake here as I am doing this per `run` (not too many multiple runs). Disregarding the number of rows (1000 was an extreme case as said previously), I just look for alternative ways for not typing manually within my codes the indexes to be removed (a bit `tedious`) once I query data over different horizons: `249, etc`

Comment: Still a bit confused as to how you arrive at the contents of rowsToRemove - is there some algorithm involved? And is your concern around populating rowsToRemove, or the efficiency of removing a large number of items from RetDist?

Comment: @IanofOz: my primary concern is about the `best` way of populating `rowsToRemove`, and then assess how `efficient` it is while attempting to remove a large number of items from `RetDist`.

Comment: Yup, got that. But the question remains how do you decide what needs to be in rowsToRemove? What is the exact algorithm used to determine what should be in there? Can't really comment on the best way to popuate rowsToRemove without knowing what should be in there.

Comment: @IanofOz: `algorithm` could be a 'big' word here. I've thus updated the post with a potential solution i had in mind but did not want to write into my codes since i was looking for a more `efficient` one.

Comment: Can you not encapsulate that logic in a Predicate (function returning bool) and just use Linq's RemoveAll?